# BeautifulSoup is returing none

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a value from a website using beautiful soup but it keeps returning none. This is what I have for my code so far

```
def getmarketchange():
    source = requests.get("https://www.coinbase.com/price").text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    marketchange = soup.get("MarketHealth__Percent-sc-1a64a42-2.bEMszd")
    print(marketchange)

getmarketchange()
```

and attached is a screenshot of html code I was trying to grab.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: There's an excellent chance the data you're looking for is not actually in the page's HTML source, but is instead loaded via javascript after the page loads. Download the HTML to a file and inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the HTML source returned from your `get()` request - it's a CAPTCHA challenge.  You won't be able to get to the Coinbase pricing without passing this challenge.

Excerpt:

```
<h2 class="cf-subheadline"><span data-translate="complete_sec_check">
  Please complete the security check to access</span> www.coinbase.com
</h2>

<div class="cf-section cf-highlight cf-captcha-container">
```

Coinbase is recognizing that the HTTP request isn't coming from a standard browser-based user, and it is challenging the requester.  BeautifulSoup doesn't have a way to pass this check on its own.

Passing in `User-Agent` headers (to mimic a browser request) also doesn't resolve this issue.

For example:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

source = requests.get("https://www.coinbase.com/price", headers=headers).text
```

You might find better luck with [Selenium,](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) although I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a captcha page, try to specify `User-Agent` header:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.coinbase.com/price'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('[class^="MarketHealth__Percent"]').text)
```

Prints:

```
0.65%
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However I did try that and it threw me the error,  "AttributError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'